# PHP and Mysql (pulling information)

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I am working on a little project of my own building a PHP form that submits to a Mysql database. I have now managed to connect the form to the database and all is working on that side.

I am now looking at creating a page that displays my information from mysql if the date field and todays date is over 14 days.

I have managed to create a page that displays all of my information however i appear to have got stuck on the 14 days part.

This is the code i have so far:

```
<title>Force 10 - Reminder app</title>
<h2>F10 - Reminder app - all invoice</h2>

<?php
include 'db-connect.php'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM invoices");

echo "<table border='0' align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Company Name:</th>
<th>Email:</th>
<th>Address:</th>
<th>Price:</th>
<th>Date:</th>
<th>File:</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['file'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If somone can help me out on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: you might want to define your variables within your while, and then do an insert into the database.  Look up tutorials on MySQL inserts, and then prepare the variables and insert them into the database.  You should really use object oriented style. Here's a good tutorial, including your database connection:   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You explained the background and what you have now. Can you clarify the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to query the db to select records that are more than 14 days older than the current date?

```
select * from `invoices` where datediff(now(),`date`) > 14
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using `$row['companyname']` is not for when using `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`. This pulls an array out of the database for each column, so the first column would be `$row[0]`instead of `$row['companyname']`.

If you want to pull columns by name, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` instead, like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['file'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

You could also look into using prepared statement and such, they are used a bit differently than this, but it'll become a much more secure script when using variables in your SQL-queries.

If you wish to only select invoices that is older than 14 days, you have to modify your `SELECT`-query, adding a `WHERE`-clause:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY");
```